# PTY.getpty で実行したコマンドの出力を IO#read で取得する際、処理時間 (sleep の有無) で結果が変わってしまう

Tags: ruby

Ruby で PTY.getpty でコマンドを実行し、その出力 (標準出力・標準エラー出力) を取得したいと考えています。

ためしに下記のようなコードを書いたのですが、1つめの PTY.getpty 呼び出しでは期待通りコマンドの出力 `"1\r\n"` が得られる一方、2つめの PTY.getpty 呼び出しでは r.eof? が最初から `true` になり、コマンドの出力が得られません (r.eof? の前に r.read を呼んでも nil が返ってきます)。

```rb
require "pty"

puts "1. without sleep"
PTY.getpty("echo 1") {|r, w, pid|
  # sleep 1
  until r.eof?
    p r.read(1000)
  end
  p PTY.check(pid)
}

puts "2. with sleep"
PTY.getpty("echo 1") {|r, w, pid|
  sleep 1
  until r.eof?
    p r.read(1000)
  end
  p PTY.check(pid)
}
```

1つめと2つめの違いは `sleep 1` の有無だけですが、

1. なぜ `sleep` の有無によって結果が変わるのか
2. 安定してコマンドの出力を得る方法があるか

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると幸いです。

(上記の例であれば Open3.capture3 などでも実装できると思いますが、実際には IO#expect を使ってパスワードの自動入力を行いたいため PTY.getpty を使っています)

環境:
macOS Monterey 12.2.1
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-darwin21]